# Counting the size of a sample space

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

I want to count the size of a sample space as follows:

5 people each roll two die. What is the size of the sample space?

I know the sample space for rolling two die is $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\} \times \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ so it is size 36.

Now for the sample space of 5 people, I decided to describe the sample space by forming 5-tuples, where the first element of the tuple would be the result of the first person's two die, the second element would be the second person's two die, and so on. Hence, the number of ways is simply the number of unique 5-tuple permutations from 36 choices, which is 36 P 5.

However I received the wrong answer according to the solutions manual. I would like to know what went wrong in my logic.

Comment: Your idea of the tuples works fine, but your count is incorrect.  Why would it be permutations?  Can't two people make the same roll? ¶ To be honest, the question is underspecified if that's all there is.  It's unclear from the problem statement alone whether each person's roll is to be represented by the individual die rolls or their sum; if it is the individual rolls, are the dice distinguishable?  (I.e., is 5-6 distinct from 6-5?)  And so on.

Comment: @BrianTung Hi thanks for your comment. The dice are indeed distinguishable so 5-6 and 6-5 are different. Although I am confused on permutations, because I don't think combinations work here. Would it be 36 x 36 x 36 x 36 x 36, because of the repetition allowed?

Comment: Based on the comment  of @BrianTung and your response, under the assumption that both the dice and the people are distinguishable, I would say that the size of the sample space is $(36)^5.$  As Brian Tung questioned, I also would normally have questioned whether the sample space can be restricted to the sum of the two dice that a person rolls, rather than the individual counts on the dice.  However, the premise that the dice are distinguishable **seems to** exclude that interpretation.